# Rating system stars are not displaying according to the number it has

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Se5Jo.png)I have a problem i cannot solve.I am making a rating system and whatever highest rating out of 5 is on the last article,every single article gets that displayed in stars.I dont know what i am doing wrong and was wondering if someone can check it out thank you.
img: https://gyazo.com/61e0a1638821e1bf542f372a30ea8ee1

The code is pretty big so i will include the important stuff.

```
<?php
$query = $db->query("SELECT article.id,article.title, AVG(ratings.rates) AS rating 
                     FROM article LEFT JOIN ratings ON article.title = ratings.title 
                     GROUP BY article.id")

while ($show = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo "<a href='rate.php?id=".$show['id']."&title=".$show['title']."'><h1>".$show['title']."</h1></a><ul>
    <li><label for='rating_1' class='rating1'><i class='fas fa-star'></i></label><input type='radio' name='ratings' id='rating_1' value='1'></li>
    <li><label for='rating_2' class='rating2'><i class='fas fa-star'></i></label><input type='radio' name='ratings' id='rating_2' value='2'></li>
    <li><label for='rating_3' class='rating3'><i class='fas fa-star'></i></label><input type='radio' name='ratings' id='rating_3' value='3'></li>
    <li><label for='rating_4' class='rating4'><i class='fas fa-star'></i></label><input type='radio' name='ratings' id='rating_4' value='4'></li>
    <li><label for='rating_5' class='rating5'><i class='fas fa-star'></i></label><input type='radio' name='ratings' id='rating_5' value='5'></li>
    </ul>";
    echo "".round($show['rating'])."";
   $number= $show['rating'];

    echo "<script language='javascript'>
    if ($number>=1) {
        $('.rating1').css({'color':'blue'});
    }
    if ($number>=2) {
        $('.rating2').css({'color':'blue'});
    }
    if ($number>=3) {
        $('.rating3').css({'color':'blue'});
    }
    if ($number>=4) {
        $('.rating4').css({'color':'blue'});
    }
    if ($number>=5) {
        $('.rating5').css({'color':'blue'});
    }
    </script>
    ";
}
?>
```

Comment: oh i forgot to include $number= $show['rating'];

Comment: why use js at all?

Comment: Why are you doing that class setting in javascript anyway? You could just concat the class of blue as you are outputting the rows.... `echo '<li><label for="rating_3" class="rating3 '. (($number>=3)?'blue':'') .'">...`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone for the stars to change

Comment: I'm agree with LawrenceCherone and IncredibleHat. No need to javascript for the creation of the stars. But I've made an answer for your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the same classes for each rows. So, all rows takes the values of the last `$number`. You could include the ID like this to make all different :

```
while ($show = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

    echo "<a href='rate.php?id=".$show['id']."&title=".$show['title']."'><h1>".$show['title']."</h1></a><ul>
    <li><label for='rating_1' class='rating1_".$show['id']."'><i class='fas fa-star'></i></label><input type='radio' name='ratings' id='rating_1' value='1'></li>
    <li><label for='rating_2' class='rating2_".$show['id']."'><i class='fas fa-star'></i></label><input type='radio' name='ratings' id='rating_2' value='2'></li>
    <li><label for='rating_3' class='rating3_".$show['id']."'><i class='fas fa-star'></i></label><input type='radio' name='ratings' id='rating_3' value='3'></li>
    <li><label for='rating_4' class='rating4_".$show['id']."'><i class='fas fa-star'></i></label><input type='radio' name='ratings' id='rating_4' value='4'></li>
    <li><label for='rating_5' class='rating5_".$show['id']."'><i class='fas fa-star'></i></label><input type='radio' name='ratings' id='rating_5' value='5'></li>
    </ul>";
    echo "".round($show['rating'])."";
    $number= $show['rating'];

    echo "<script language='javascript'>
    if ($number>=1) {
        $('.rating1_".$show['id']."').css({'color':'blue'});
    }
    if ($number>=2) {
        $('.rating2_".$show['id']."').css({'color':'blue'});
    }
    if ($number>=3) {
        $('.rating3_".$show['id']."').css({'color':'blue'});
    }
    if ($number>=4) {
        $('.rating4_".$show['id']."').css({'color':'blue'});
    }
    if ($number>=5) {
        $('.rating5_".$show['id']."').css({'color':'blue'});
    }
    </script>
    ";
}
```

Also you have multiple times the same id and should be :

```
echo "<li><label for='rating_1_".$show['id']."' class='rating1_".$show['id']."'><i class='fas fa-star'></i></label><input type='radio' name='ratings' id='rating_1_".$show['id']."' value='1'></li>"
```

Comment: Good catch on there being multiple `id`. One of the most common pitfalls I see when people put html into loops.

Comment: Thank you @IncredibleHat ! I think that your comment (under the question) was very wise, and hope OP followed your advice.

Comment: omg it worked thank you so much really appreciate your help ^_^